# Is this a simple way to ensure Sunspot Solr starts or this bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have had many problems with Sunspot Solr not being started, particularly after server reboot initiated by the Host.

Now I am sure there are ways that I could create a startup script that my server would run, or maybe monit is the way to go.  But I am think all I really need is to start the Solr server when my app starts, so just now I put this in an initializer:

```
begin
  Sunspot::Rails::Server.new.start
rescue
  # solr is already running
end
```

Tried it locally and it seemed to work.

Is this terrible? Is there a quick and easy way that is better?

Answer (score 8):

According to the Sunspot documentation they don't recommend using the built in instance for anything other than development.

From the Sunspot::Rails README:

> To start up a Solr instance, issue the
> following:
>
> `rake sunspot:solr:start`
>
> Note that
> using the built-in Solr instance
> packaged with Sunspot is great for
> development, but is not recommended
> for production. See the Sunspot
> documentation for more information.

See this link for the referenced documentation (wiki entry): https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configuring-solr-for-use-with-sunspot-in-development%2C-testing%2C-and-production

Comment: +1 for this. In production you need a proper init script, and ideally monit set up to keep an eye on Solr's responsiveness.